# ionic - open local PDF file

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

My ionic app uses the Cordova plugin inAppBrowser. I’ve updated my ionic & cordova environment; and updated cordova-plugin-inappbrowser to version 1.7.2

Now this line of code does nothing (it worked 6 months ago):

```
var targetPath = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp/files/myDir/fds/30510L109.pdf";
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open(targetPath, “_system”, { location: ‘no’, clearcache: ‘yes’, toolbar: ‘yes’, closebuttoncaption: $translate.instant(“SCAN.BACK”), EnableViewPortScale:‘yes’ });
```

I don’t get any error in the console (when I run the app using: ionic cordova run android -lc), and nothing happens…
How can I know what’s wrong?

Comment: you need to use chrome inspect devices to check out whats the error in device console

Comment: After some research and debug, I've found that this exception is thrown: [FileUriExposedException][1]. It seems to be a change introduced in Android SDK 24 ([link][2])

I read this solution: [link][3], but I already use cordova.file.externalDataDirectory to save my PDF...


  [1]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html
  [2]: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en
  [3]: https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2/issues/28#issuecomment-218442994

Comment: file external data directory will return you a built in sdcard path. This path you mentioned  - "storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp/files/myDir/fds/" is not from external data directory I feel

Comment: cordova.file.externalDataDirectory returns: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp/files/

Comment: jus check if this link helps - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Comment: This code works on my Android. So, I integrated it in my app, still same problem... So, I've compared both projects, and found you're using cordova-plugin-fileopener2 version 2.0.19, and I was using 2.0.20. I've installed 2.0.19 and now it works!!

Comment: shall I post the answer so that you can accept the same?

Comment: yes, just do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the OP's comment, the issue is with the version of Cordova file opener2 plugin. Version 2.0.19 seems to be working fine but not 2.0.20

The working sample of Cordova file operations is available in this [git repo](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations) This should help resolving most of your file operations related issues in Cordova app. Hope is helps.